# Postgresql unique count satisfying two conditions

Tags: postgresql, count, distinct, count-unique

I am relatively new programmer. I am trying to create a left join with count of unique rows in a specific column.
with normal count it is working fine, nut with unique it is failing.

```
count(case when x.priorities = 112 then 1 end) as Urgent.
```

it is pulling all the records. I need to convert it into unique records.

i am looking for a direction or syntax which i can try.

Comment: You should really add an example. Maybe you just mean `... = 112 and xxx = yyy`

Comment: If you want to count unique records only use DISTINCT keyword with count function.

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "COUNT(DISTINCT..)" clause instead of "COUNT".

Here is a simple example to do this(if we have a table named "students" with a column "department" and we want to count the number of unique departments represented in the table):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT department) AS unique_departments FROM students;
```

For your requirement try this:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN t2.any_column = 112 THEN t2.any_column END) AS unique_values
```

*Replace column names as per your need.*